# Application == session == connection in DB2?

Tags: db2, session, terminology

Can I consider as synonyms Applications, Sessions and Connections in DB2 LUW?

In db2top, I see "Sessions". There is a command "db2 force applications", views and other stuff. And from the developer point of view it is a "connection"

May I use them interchangeably when talking about connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd argue that you should *not* consider applications, connections and sessions synonymous.

An application is an instance of a running software program, materialized as an operating system process. An application may or may not establish one or more connections to a database, however, as @IanBjorhovde mentions,  if you look at it from the database manager perspective you only know about those applications that are connected, though multiple connections can eventually lead to the same application on the other side.

I guess for historical reasons the DB2 terminology is a bit confusing: instead of `list applications` or `force application` there should have been `list connections` and `force connection`.

A session is implicitly created when a connection is established between an application and the database. It is a specific context, that is, a set of variables controlling SQL statement execution. However, you can switch sessions without terminating the connection, e.g. by changing a trusted context within a connection.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, application == connection == session *when looking at it from DB2's perspective*.

Someone could probably make an argument that these aren't always necessarily the same in environments using connection concentrator or the database partitioning feature (DPF), but for all intents and purposes it's safe to use the terms interchangeably.

You could also make the argument that, from the client-side, a single application may open multiple connections (i.e. a connection pool), but this is dba.stackexchange.com :-)